# Built-In Azure policy definition

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

There used to be a Built-In Azure Policy definition called "Require specified tag" that is no longer there. Is there a reason that it was removed with no replacement? Does anyone have the JSON code for this old policy definition?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this policy:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Require a tag on resources",
    "policyType": "BuiltIn",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Enforces existence of a tag. Does not apply to resource groups.",
    "metadata": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "category": "Tags"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Name",
          "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
        "exists": "false"
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/871b6d14-10aa-478d-b590-94f262ecfa99",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "871b6d14-10aa-478d-b590-94f262ecfa99"
}
```

These policies are present as built-in policies for "Require tags".

[image]

Comment: Yes! That ended up being the replacement for the deprecated "Require a specific tag" policy definition. Thank you.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: I dont see that option.

Comment: Click on the tick button on the left side of the answer. Click it to accept it.